# Create Docker instance .tar including volumes

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have a local Gitlab docker image running and added a bunch of projects. This project/repository data seems to end up inside of the 3 volumes that have been created by the image.

I want to create a single .tar of the Gitlab instance which includes the complete image + all data found in the volumes. It's okay that the .tar becomes huge.

I tried to accomplish this by using docker commit and docker save but I have been unable to save the volumes along with the image.

How can I create such a single .tar export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was going to set this up, I'd have a single Docker Compose file that contained all of the relevant pieces in a single directory tree.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:11'
    volumes:
      - './postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab-community-edition
    # Details below here made up
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    env:
      PGHOST: db
    volumes:
      - './gitlab:/data'
```

The important thing here is that every piece of persisted data is in the same directory tree on the host.  The actual contents of the container filesystem aren't important (every piece of persisted data is in these directories) and the images aren't important (they can be pulled from Docker Hub).

Comment: Thanks, after reading your comment I will go this route somewhat by assigning volumes outside of the container in a single directory and just zip/tar that directory and write a little guide on how to run any gitlab instance with this backup folder as volumes and thus all data

Answer (score 0):

You may use `docker cp` to achieve this.

`docker cp my_container:/path/to/gitlab /destination/folder`

and then tar the contents of the destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to use docker export to create the tar of the image. Docker import then to install it back. Essentially you’re looking for an installer from the sounds of it. You can write a bash script which copies whatever files you need and exports the images.